# Data attribute array value inside a php string

Tags: php, custom-data-attribute

I'm trying to pass an array value for a data attribute inside a php string but I'm getting the error (syntax error, unexpected 'event' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';')

```
echo '<div class="element-search" data-page-type="event" data-search-types="['event', 'person']">';
```

Comment: use this `echo '<div class="element-search" data-page-type="event" data-search-types="[\'event\', \'person\']">';`, you must escape single quotes `'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the qoutes. So `'` will become `\'`